# Correct order for a sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery

Following [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/50q1ryxf/), I would like to choose from the top to the bottom:

Word2 then Word1 and finally Word3 3

The result displayed is:

```
Word2 2 Word1 1 Word3 3
```

But I am looking for something like:

```
Word1 1 Word2 2 Word3 3
```

So once I choose Word1, it should be placed at the beginning followed by Word2.

If anyone can help correcting the bug on my code:

```
function nextItemWasAlreadyShown(index) {
  var continueLoop = false;
  var resText = $('.displayCheck').html();
  var text = $('select.ayaNum').eq(index).next('input[type="hidden"]').val();
  if (resText.indexOf(text) > -1) continueLoop = true;
    return continueLoop;
  }

function getValues() { 
  var result = [];
  var me = this; 
  $('select.ayaNum').each(function (idx, el) {
    var $el = $(el);
    var textToAdd = $el.next('input[type="hidden"]').val() + ' ' + $el.val();
    result.splice(idx, 0, textToAdd);
    if ((me === el) && !nextItemWasAlreadyShown(idx + 1)) return false;
  });
  $('.displayCheck').html(result.join(' '));
}

$('select.ayaNum,input[type="hidden"]').change(getValues);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: on the select menu, try to choose word2, then word1, then word3, the order displayed is: Word2 2 Word1 1 Word3 3, so I am looking for something like Word1 1 Word2 2 Word3 3, re-order them from small number to bigger one

Comment: And what if i select 3 1 2 then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
 $('.displayCheck').html(result.join(' '));
```

to

```
 $('.displayCheck').html(result.sort().join(' '));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50q1ryxf/2/)

**EDIT:** for the question about sorting based on the number following the word.

change

```
$('.displayCheck').html(result.sort().join(' '));
```

to

```
$('.displayCheck').html(result.sort(function (a, b) {      
    return +a.split(' ')[1] - +b.split(' ')[1];        
}).join(' '));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50q1ryxf/10/)

and the followup example you could change:

```
$('.displayCheck').html(result.sort(function (a, b) {      
    return +a.split(' ')[1] - +b.split(' ')[1];        
}).join(' '));
```

to

```
$('.displayCheck').html(result.sort(function (a, b) {      
    return +a.split(' ')[a.split(' ').length-1] - +b.split(' ')[b.split(' ').length-1] ;        
}).join(' '));
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9vrzdeuu/2/)

I would consider changing how you are storing the result array.  `var result = [];` Might change it to an array of objects with `text, value` like:

```
var results = [
  {
    "text": theTextOfTheOption,
    "value": theValueOfTheOption
  },
  {
    ...
  }
];
```

Then you could sort based on the `value` rather than doing the splits on the strings in your results array.

Comment: yeah correct Ryan Gill, how about if I would like to order them following the number NOT the word, i.e: Word2 1 Word3 2 Word2 3, so in this case we order the numbers

Comment: I used another example to clarify my question http://jsfiddle.net/9vrzdeuu/ so from the top I will choose Learning as number 2, then I am as number 1 and finally JS as number 3, the result will be Learning 2 I am 1 JS 3, but it should be ordered like: I am 1 Learning 2 JS 3

Comment: I did not get it, I changed the var result = []; by the above code, but it does NOT work